# In windows, what is the difference between named and unnamed semaphores?

Tags: mutex, semaphore

What is the difference between named and unnamed semaphores?
For Example in Windows, we always do `WaitforSingleObject`( wait) and `ReleaseSemaphore`( Signal ) using the `HANDLE`s and not using names.

Answer (score 2):

An unnamed semaphore can only be used by its handle, but if you have a named semaphore you can create a second handle using the name. The benefit of this is that you only need to have a static name to be able to use the same semaphore in different threads and processes.